# Restarting / Autorepairing Mongodb in Production

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos, fedora

What I want to achieve is to have an /etc/init.d script which more reliably starts Mongodb, even if it went down hard -- it should attempt an auto-repair in case the system is in a locked state.

Yes, I could script this myself, but I think somebody out there must have done this already.

I noticed that after a server goes down hard, that Mongodb is in a state where it doesn't restart via the /etc/init.d/mongod script.  Obviously the lock file(s) need to be removed and it needs to be started with the --repair option and correct --dbpath first, before it can be successfully restarted.   In some cases one also needs to change the ownership of the db-files to the user who runs mongodb.  One additional problem is that the standard /etc/init.d/mongod script does not report a failure in this situation, but rather joyfully and incorrectly returns with "OK" status, reporting that Mongod was started, although it wasn't.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mongod start
Starting mongod: forked process: 9220
all output going to: /data/mongo/log/mongod.log
                                                           [  OK  ]
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mongod status
mongod dead but subsys locked
```

The OS is either CentOS or Fedora.

**Does anybody have modified /etc/init.d scripts or a pointer to such scripts, which attempt a repair automatically in that situation?**  Or is there another tool which functions as a watch dog for Mongod?

**Any opinions on why it might be a bad idea to try to automatically repair mongodb?**

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mongod status
mongod dead but subsys locked

$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock 
-rw-r--r--. 1 mongod mongod 5 Nov 19 11:52 /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock


$ sudo tail -50 /data/mongo/log/mongod.log
************** 
old lock file: /data/mongo/db/mongod.lock.  probably means unclean shutdown
recommend removing file and running --repair
see: http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair for more information
*************
Sat Nov 19 11:55:44 exception in initAndListen std::exception: old lock file, terminating
Sat Nov 19 11:55:44 dbexit: 

Sat Nov 19 11:55:44 shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sat Nov 19 11:55:44 shutdown: going to flush oplog...
Sat Nov 19 11:55:44 shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sat Nov 19 11:55:44 shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sat Nov 19 11:55:44 shutdown: closing all files...
Sat Nov 19 11:55:44     closeAllFiles() finished

Sat Nov 19 11:55:44 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the first bit to mention is journaling. Journaling is effectively billed as "fast repair". Journaling is on by default in 2.0+ and it will perform that "repair" by default.

So if your disks can handle the extra write-throughput of journaling this may solve your problem.

> Any opinions on why it might be a bad idea to try to automatically repair mongodb?

The #1 issue with repairing MongoDB automatically is simply one of time.

If you have a 200GB database, the system will need to do the following when repairing:

1. Allocate ~200GB of files (*do you have the drive space?*)
2. Read all of the data from the existing files into memory (`200GB read`)
3. Check each document for validity and write it back to the new files (`200GB write`)
4. Re-create all indexes (`200GB reads + large number of writes`)
5. Flush everything to disk

If you look at my notes that's a serious amount of drive thrashing to perform a repair.

But most production installs are running replica sets. In this case, instead of repairing, you can just restore from a backup. Restoring from a backup only writes the data once and it's a process you should already have in place.

Despite the `init.d` script returning `OK`, your system monitoring should tell you that the DB is not up.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. Journaling looks like the way to go.. which version did they introduce journaling?

Comment: Journaling was introduced in 1.8+, just set the `journal=true` in your config file. In 2.0+ journaling is active by default. Note that journaling is not "free". It does not work on 32-bit, it will use additional RAM, additional disk space and additional IO. If you do a lot of in-place updates (like counters), this could be significant. So do test the journaling mode before a blind push to production.

Comment: Great answer! although it's not really a script :) The journaling will probably do the trick. 32-bit isn't an issue for me. I'll try out the journaling! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just want to point out that journaling *does* work in the 32-bit version.  However, it is not on by default in 32-bit.

Comment: It's correct that journalling is [disabled by default](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling#Journaling-32bitnuances%3F) on 32-bit versions and can be enabled .. but note that enabling will reduce the amount of (already limited) memory you have available for your database.  There are many [limitations of the 32-bit builds](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/32+bit), and you should always use 64-bit for production.

Comment: you most definitely have a typo in your answer... 32-bit vs 32-bit? ;)

Comment: Tilo, sorry if my wording was made awkward by repeating "32-bit".  Journaling works in the 32-bit version, however it is not on by default.