# MongoDB "Connection refused" error

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, yii

I  wanted to know what is the actual reason behind MongoDB "connection refused " error and How can we prevent this from happening.I am  using ubuntu server.

I found that we can solve the problem after it has occured by:

```
sudo -u mongodb mongod --repair -dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
sudo start mongodb
```

I would like to know the way how can we stop it from occurring rather than solving it after it has occurred

The scenario is:

Mongodb is running well but after sometime I get this error .What I am doing in that span of time is I am continuously inserting data to that mongodb database in an interval of 1 minute.

I am using yii's yiiMongoDbsuite extension.The actual error thrown is.

```
EMongoDB failed to open connection: Failed to connect to: xx.xxx.xxx.xx:27017:
Connection refused
```

I would really appreciate if somebody helps me in this case.Thanks.

Comment: Are there any other messages in the logs?  I would check `db.serverStatus().connections` and see if you are running out of available connections and perhaps need to increase your [`ulimits`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/).  Running a 'repair' should be unrelated to connections (and very unnecessary/unhelpful as a remedy for the described problem).  Is this system monitored in MMS?

Comment: @Pratik How you are inserting the data. Are you creating connection every time of insertion? Post the insertion code so that it's easy to debug and help.

Comment: @ Karthick.k Actually I am using nodejs  and I am making connection only once. It works perfect initially but after about 15,20 or more  minutes of continuos data insertion in an interval of 1 min.. ,it throws that error @Stennie I increased ulimit for number of user processes in ubuntu server .. Let see  what happens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look if Journaling is turned on in your settings, for more information, please refer to this previously answered question

[Restarting / Autorepairing Mongodb in Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274950/restarting-autorepairing-mongodb-in-production)

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt install -y mongodb
```

Try this...this will solve your problem